# List index is out of range, but I cannot understand why

Tags: python, list, matrix, while-loop

This is a function that I've written to linearly interpolate each index in a matrix (each index is a list comprised of five values, where the goal is to determine the sixth).
I keep getting an error stating that the list index is out of range, but I don't see how. I believe that I'm missing something really small, but I can't determine the issue.
This is a small part of a large project, and I think I've been looking at this for too long. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
tbi = [[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000], [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]]

def interpolate():
    interpolated_vals = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(tbi):
        interpolated_vals.append(tbi[i][0]+((tbi[i][3] - tbi[i][2])*(tbi[i][1] - tbi[i][0])/(tbi[i][4] - [i][2])))
        i += 1

    return interpolated_vals
```

Comment: Typo  - [i][2]) ?

Comment: You have got to be kidding me... Thanks so much, I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: It happens ;-) Not only to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end of line `interpolated_vals.append(...`

> ```
> [i][2])))
> ```

must be

```
 tbi[i][2])))
```

After the correction the function returns `[1500, 1500]`

Comment: @ChaddRobertson hehe yes, typical error we do not see because we do not read the code as it is but as it must be

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `tbi` at the end:

`interpolated_vals.append(tbi[i][0]+((tbi[i][3] - tbi[i][2])*(tbi[i][1] - tbi[i][0])/(tbi[i][4] - [i][2])))`

should be:

`interpolated_vals.append(tbi[i][0]+((tbi[i][3] - tbi[i][2])*(tbi[i][1] - tbi[i][0])/(tbi[i][4] - tbi[i][2])))`